# A state is undefined object when using React and Redux , Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Im developing apps with React and Redux , Router.
But now  I can't set(update) a state into the state of 'mapStateToProps' function.
So a reducer's args 'action' is 'undefined'.
I think the cause of this problem is that mapStateToProps's args is not passed from anywhere.

Does anyone know how to pass a state(data input from client) into mapStateToProps function?

My mapStateToProps function is simply written like this.

```
const mapStateToProps = state=>{
console.log(state);  // this 'state' return undefined.
return {
loginform: state
}};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginForm)
```

Here is my code.

## Index

/index.js

```
let store = createStore(showUsername,
window.devToolsExtension && window.devToolsExtension() );

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route component={AppNavBar}>
        <IndexRedirect to='/login'>
        <Route path='/login' component={LoginForm} />
    </Route>
</Router>
</Provider>
,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

## Component

/Loginform.js

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    ...
}

const mapStateToProps = state=>{
console.log(state);  // this 'state' return undefined.
return {
    loginform: state
}};


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginForm)
```

## ActionCreator

/actioncreator.js

```
    export const showusername = 'showUsername';

    export const showUsername =(username,index)=>{
    console.log(username,index);
    return{
        type:showusername,
        username,
        payload:index
    }

    };
```

**#Reducer**

/reducer.js

```
    const initialState = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            submit: false,
            //request: 'self',
            showselectfield: false
        };

    export default function showUsername(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case type.showusername:
      return (
          Object.assign({},initialState ,{username:action.username,password:action.password})
          );

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your reducer when you check for the action that was triggered, you are checking for `type.showusername` but since you already have `action.type` in the switch case you should check for simply the string value i.e. `"showusername"`

```
const initialState = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            submit: false,
            //request: 'self',
            showselectfield: false
        };

    export default function showUsername(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "showusername":
      return (
          Object.assign({},state ,{username:action.username,password:action.password})
          );

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the case value and worked well.But still 'action.username' is undefined.

Comment: Are you able to see username in the actionCreator console.log() statement

Comment: When I see console.log(username) , it shows undefined.

Comment: I also set console.log(state) inside of  mapStateToProps function, but the state show undefined too. So I was thinking this is the cause of problem. Is this normal the state of  mapStateToProps function show undefined?

Comment: showusername takes the username as a input argument, how are you providing that because otherwise it will return null

Comment: In your reducer change initialState to state with object.assign and see, because it should be normal for mapStateToProps show undefined. Also try writing state in parentheis like (state) in mapStateToProps